# How to fix the speed of calling storyboard in swift code when make a if condition in API?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an API that check if username and password are correct when correct come back with value "1" CHK ="1" and when calling and check the value I print console with message , message comes fast when I click it comes but switch to the Home storyboard it takes time and sometimes it's not working.

```
if let url = urlString {
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,        response, error) in
            if  let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                if let unwrappedData = data {

                    do{
                        //let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData, options: []) as AnyObject

                        if let JsonDic = json[0] as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            if let check = JsonDic["CHK"] {
                                if let check1 = check as? String {
                                    if check1 == "1" {
                                        let HomeViewControler = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
                                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeViewControler, animated: true)
                                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                                        print("You Are ready to login")
                                    }else{
                                        print("You Enterd a wrong password or Mail")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }catch{
                        print("There are an Error")
                    }
```

Comment: You have a couple of issues.  Your speed issue is probably because your closure is executing on a thread other than the main thread. Dispatch the UI updates onto the main thread. The other issue you have is that you are simultaneously pushing a new view controller and dismissing the current view controller. You should do one or the other.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `NSDictionary` in Swift unless you absolutely have to. I suggest that you use `Codable` to create an appropriate object from your JSON

Comment: And what can I do now with this code as you suggest ?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.navigationController?.push ... }`

Comment: This Meaning That I will close the first storyboard and open the new one ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)`  and update code in

```
  if check1 == "1" 
   {
      let HomeViewControler = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeViewControler, animated: true)       
      print("You Are ready to login")
   }
```

Comment: it takes some time after print the message  "You Are ready to login"

Comment: This Message apper into console                                                                        2019-05-25 14:33:56.486 Lasik[990:22486] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Comment: As followed it works after one minute  2019-05-25 14:50:57.995973+0200 Lasik[1081:27389] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker
You Are ready to login
2019-05-25 14:51:50.517 Lasik[1081:27436] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.